# PHP5 and pdo: include sqlite module by ini_set

Tags: php, sqlite, pdo, ini-set

Is it possible to include an external php module like `do_sqlite.so` directly in a page with a `ini_set()` command, bypassing `php.ini`?
Some closed servers give only a limited mysql support...
And I want to try a hack in order to use an external pdo_sqlite.so and include it in my personal pages.

Comment: http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.dl.php ?

Comment: Thanks! i never seen it, i'll try early ^_^